# How to use json_search for numeric value

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH('[{"key":"25", "value":"12"},{"key":"12","value":"10"}]','one','12',NULL,'$**.key');
```

This works fine. It searches for the first key with value 25.

However, my data has values as numbers, which doesn't work.

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH('[{"key":25, "value":12},{"key":12,"value":10}]','one','12',NULL,'$**.key');
```

Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: Your JSON is not valid. Check here `"value":12"},`

Comment: It was a copy mistake. The query I raised is still valid. Thanks for pointing it out, fixed it

Comment: Parse then search. JSON_SEARCH searches for string data ONLY.

Comment: Can you give a sample example of parse and search? thanks